# R ggplot bar graph has extra lines at the base of columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two main issues I could use some help getting resolved. 
1.) There are odd lines at the base of my columns which I am not sure how to get rid of.
2.) I am running into overlap with the columns when I graph. (I think this has something do do with the position_dodge(width= XXX) but not totally sure).

[image: ggplot barplot issue/base of columns]

Attached an image of an example plot, mainly because I am not sure how to describe what is happening at the base of the plot.

The following code is being used.

```
where_2 <- where %>% 
  group_by_("gender", "radio") %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(perc = (perc = (count / sum(count) * 100)))

gg <- ggplot(where_2, aes_string(x = names(where_2[1]), y = where_2$perc, fill = "radio"))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..))) 
gg <-gg + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(.5),stat = "identity", width = .75)

#gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
gg <- gg + xlab(paste0(lab5[2, title]))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Yes", "No"))
print(gg)
```

I have been running in a wall for the past 4 days with this question any help would be appreciated.

```
place   gender  Radio
1   Male    No
1   Female  Yes
1   Male    No
1   Female  Yes
1   Male    Yes
1   Male    Yes
1   Female  Yes
1   Female  Yes
1   Male    Yes
1   Female  No
1   Male    Yes
1   Male    Yes
1   Male    No
1   Female  No
1   Female  Yes
1   Female  Yes
1   Female  No
1   Male    Yes
1   Female  No
1   Female  Yes
1   Female  No
1   Female  Yes
1   Male    No
1   Male    No
1   Female  No
1   Male    No
1   Female  No
1   Female  No
1   Female  No
1   Male    Yes
1   Female  No
1   Female  No
1   Female  Yes
1   Male    No
1   Male    Yes
1   Female  No
2   Male    Yes
2   Male    Yes
2   Female  No
2   Female  No
2   Male    Yes
2   Female  No
2   Male    No
2   Male    Yes
2   Female  No
2   Female  No
2   Female  No
2   Male    No
2   Female  No
2   Male    No
2   Female  Yes
2   Female  Yes
2   Male    Yes
2   Male    No
2   Male    Yes
3   Female  No
3   Male    Yes
3   Female  No
3   Male    No
3   Male    Yes
3   Female  No
3   Female  Yes
3   Male    No
3   Male    Yes
3   Female  Yes
3   Male    No
3   Female  No
3   Female  Yes
3   Female  No
3   Female  Yes
3   Female  No
3   Male    Yes
3   Female  No
3   Female  No
4   Male    Yes
4   Female  No
4   Female  Yes
4   Female  Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Female  No
4   Female  No
4   Male    No
4   Female  No
4   Female  No
4   Female  No
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Female  Yes
4   Female  No
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Female  No
4   Female  No
4   Female  No
```

Comment: Please post data to reproduce plots.

Comment: I can't release all the data, but I added a small sample of it which should get the same results I am getting now.  In the where_2 section of the code, if you change "proxy" to "gender" and run the ggplot code it should give you the same issues that I have been having.  Sorry for not adding the code initially.

Comment: I should also say the lab5 dataset is only concerned with pulling labels and has no bearing on the data.

Comment: Please scale this down to the essence of your question. You can post the aggregated data and the minimal amount of code needed to make a single plot that's giving this problem

Comment: Scaled down code and it should work and produce the plot based on the data given.  I believe the main issue with the "feet" has to do with the line. gg <- gg + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..))), but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gg <- ggplot(where2, 
             aes(x = gender, y = perc, fill = Radio)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = .75)

print(gg)
```

Explanation below:

You are right that the "feet" are indeed caused by `geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)))`. I'm not sure why you included it in the first place, but here's why it created the "feet":

**Good chart**

```
p <- ggplot(where2, aes(x = gender, y = perc, fill = Radio))

p + geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.5), width = 0.75)
```

[image: plot 1]

Above is the chart you want to get (I assume). `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` with less typing, so I used that instead.

Usually people set the same value in `position_dodge()` and `width =`, which would avoid the overlapped look. I've retained it for now to contrast with the "feet" below.

Notice also the values on the y-axis. They range from 0 to 60+.

**Bad chart**

```
p + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)))
```

[image: plot 2]

Above is the chart of the "feet", now occupying the entire plot's height. Here, `..count..` returns the number of rows for each combination of gender & Radio, while `sum(..count..)` returns the total number of rows in the data frame. The data frame, `where2`, has 4 rows, one for each combination, so the y value associated with each bar is 0.25, and the stacked height of each gender's two bars is 0.5.

I consider this the bad chart, because the visualisation is useless. When you have already counted the number of rows in your dataset yourself (going from `where` to `where2`), it's not necessary for ggplot to do it again.

**Good chart + bad chart = weird chart**

```
p + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.5), width = 0.75) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)))
```

[image: plot 3]

Above is the combined chart with both layers. Now the bad chart's bars are squeezed all the way to the bottom, since their combined height is only 0.5, while the good chart's bars stretch all the way to 60+.

data used:

```
> dput(where)
structure(list(place = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), Radio = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("place", "gender", "Radio"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -95L))

where2 <- where %>% 
  group_by(gender, Radio) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(perc = (perc = (count / sum(count) * 100))) 

> where2
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups: gender [2]
  gender Radio  count  perc
  <fctr> <fctr> <int> <dbl>
1 Female No        37  67.3
2 Female Yes       18  32.7
3 Male   No        15  37.5
4 Male   Yes       25  62.5
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for the answer and the explanation, it's very appreciated.